# Converting Python String to Date

Tags: python, datetime, date

I need to convert the Python string "Mon Aug 29 2011 18:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)" into "20110829T183000Z" and "20110829T173000Z" (Date + 1 hour).

Never have been good at remembering datetime APIs, would appreciate the help here!

Comment: I can't remember them either, but my solution is to read the docs.

Comment: yes, google is your friendgle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

google it. increasing your google skills is always better than being lazy.

> http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime
>
> ### classmethod `datetime.strptime(date_string, format)`
>
> Return a datetime corresponding to *`date_string`*, parsed according to *`format`*.
>   This is equivalent to `datetime(*(time.strptime(date_string, format)[0:6]))`.
>   `ValueError` is raised if the *`date_string`* and *`format`* can’t be parsed by
>   `time.strptime()` or if it returns a value which isn’t a time tuple.
>   See section `strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior.

Comment: :-) ..  I did google it and I did find strptime and strftime ..  thanks for being frank and honest!

Comment: no problem :D my questions here regularly come from using esoteric frameworks and languages in a uncommon fashion, googling *everything* clearly helped solving the basic problems with wider-known frameworks. but nevertheless, `strptime` is a totally stupid name for a parsing function -.-

Comment: Another alternative to Googling it that is also quicker and less likely to distract you is to go to a command-line Python interpreter prompt and type the following commands.  >>>`help(datetime)`                                   >>>`dir(datetime)`                       >>>help(datetime.datetime)             >>>help(datetime.datetime.strptime)